# Call class from /lib into rabl

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a class called "Person" in my "rails app" /lib directory.

```
module Backend
  class Person
    attr_accessor :id

    def initialize(attr = {})
         :
    end

    def some_method
      :
    end
  end
end
```

The question is how can I call this class in my rabl file? Is it possible to call it in my rabl file? I tried:

```
require 'backend/person'
object @person
   :
   :
   :
node(:my_element) { |person| Backend::Person.new(id: person.id).some_method }
```

But it does not work for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try the below way to auto load it and then access `your own Backend::Person` inside the rabl views

```
config/application.rb:
```

inside

```
# Custom directories with classes and modules you want to be autoloadable.
config.autoload_paths << Rails.root.join('lib')
```

More information you get here [Rails autoloading](http://urbanautomaton.com/blog/2013/08/27/rails-autoloading-hell/)

Comment: Why you think what is `app/lib` and not `/lib`?

Comment: user want to put it in app/lib folder  his first line " I have a class called "Person" in my rails app /lib directory."

Comment: Typo about app /lib. It should be "rails app" /lib. I updated my question above.